# Enviar correo electrónico con pdf y xml adjunto desde app Frontend con Reactjs, sin utilizar servidor

Tags: reactjs, email, frontend, apigoogle

Tengo que construir una app frontend (sin Backend), en la cual necesito poder enviar un correo electrónico con dos archivos PDF y XML adjuntos. Según [este link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196421/is-it-possible-to-send-mail-using-only-react) es posible, utilizando el [API de Google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest). Hasta ahí todo bien, pero alguien me puede decir si esa API me deja enviar un correo con los archivos que mencioné? Gracias

Comment: Si, pero ¿con cuáles credenciales realizarás la autenticación?